# update object in object?

Tags: mongodb, meteor

**This my update collection object in object statusDate field I change from this to second code but do not work**
​​

**this my collection**

```
{
"_id" : "001-8",
"referenceType" : "Invoice",
"refNo" : "00000001",
"tranDate" : ISODate("2018-04-04T21:10:33.419+07:00"),
"customerId" : "0001",
"setting" : {
    "accountId" : "Vendor Deposit",
    "tradeDiscount" : "Discount Received"
},
"statusDate" : {
    "active" : ISODate("2018-04-04T21:10:33.420+07:00")
},
```

**this my code it work but i want work with my second code but it not work**

```
Sale.update(
  {
    _id: invoiceId,
    customerId: customerId,
  },
  {
    $set: {
      status: status,          
      'statusDate.closed': tranDate,
    },

  }
)
```

**I do something like but not work**

```
let statusDate = {}
statusDate['statusDate.closed'] = moment().toDate()
Sale.update(
  {
    _id: invoiceId,
    customerId: customerId,
  },
  {
    $set: {
      status: status,
      statusDate     
    }
  }
)
```

Comment: Add some more details...

Comment: i show som status date details you can see

Comment: please post some data.

Comment: I add my collection ready

Comment: do you really don't see the difference between your two "codes"? in the second one you put an object. what you want to do is: `Sale.update(
  {
    _id: invoiceId,
    customerId: customerId,
  },
  {
    $set: {
      status: status,          
      'statusDate.closed': moment().toDate()
    }
  }
)`

Comment: i need my second update code because i have the some condition to check it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can not pass object with update query .
Instead you can use findOneAndUpdate

```
    let statusDate = {}
    let status=true`
    let data =     
     {
      statusDate.["statusDate.closed"]:moment().toDate(),
      status:status 
     }

    sales.findOneAndUpdate(
     {_id: invoiceId,
    customerId: customerId}
    ,{$set:data}
     )
```